# Can I change the default increment amount for an object's Transform properties?

Tags: objects, transforms

In object mode when modifying scale, rotation or location of an object. How does one:

1. Choose the amount of units changed when clicking the small arrow in the "Object" --> "Transform" menu next to the current value? Is it even possible.
   Example: your object's X location is -1.0000 and you want to modify it with (10,000 = 0.1) each click. (default change is 1,000 = 0.01)
2. Change the position, rotation or scale with the mouse and having even numbers when moving the object. With (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+mouse) you can move and snap the object every 1.0 unit, but it's kind of a large movement, and when normally using mouse to drag the object it results something like "-2.45459".
   So is there any way other than making all symmetric objects in a huge scale where the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ mouse snap 1.0 movement would be called smallish movement.

For both of these I tried to find a settings menu to change the default values, but I found nothing. Also the 2) can be done in some way, since I saw one guy in some video moving object while it snapped every 0.01 units.

Answer (score 3):

1) I haven't found any way to change the increment factor when clicking the arrows in the transform panel. I use metric units and at every click it snaps 1 cm (for Location), it is 0.01 if you don't use any unit type.

Personally if I want to move , rotate or scale an object with smaller values, for example if I want to move it 0.5 mm on the X axis I type in the values: "**G**"(for grab) -> "**X**" (on X axis) -> "**.0005**"(for 0.5 mm) -> **RETURN**

2) **Snapping**.

By default snapping is set to "INCREMENT" and it means exactly an unit seen  in the 3D viewport. It doesn't have to be 1 Unit (Meter). 
These snapping values are set by the grid seen when you are in ortographic view (NUMPAD 5 to toggle):

[image]

If you zoom in , you'll see the grid changing from 1 unit to 0.1 units and then to 0.01 units and so on as you zoom in and also the Indication in the upper Left corner will change from Meters to Centimeters, Millimeters. Now if you move an object holding CTRL the snap will be relative to those units.

To fine even more your snap you can hold **CTRL + SHIFT** while transforming and this will make the snap be **10x** shorter.

P.S. You can change the type of element to snap to from increment to vertex, edge, face volume using the shortcut **CTRL + SHIFT + TAB**